# Binary search tree using stack

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

I'm attempting to create a binary search tree without using a recursion to walk through the tree. The code attached works for initializing the tree, but when I try to walk through it, it keeps giving me the "object reference not set to instant of object" when trying to push to the stack in the GetEnumerator() method. I realize that this means I need to push an instance instead of the class itself, but how can I make an instance of "this", so to speak? Or is the only way to implement with stack is to create a separate class that holds the tree? The code is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class BinarySearchTree : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public int value;
    public BinarySearchTree left;
    public BinarySearchTree right;
    Stack<BinarySearchTree> stacks;
    public BinarySearchTree(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public BinarySearchTree(IEnumerable<int> values)
    {
        this.value = values.First();
        foreach (var val in values.Skip(1))
        {
            this.Add(val);
        }
    }
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.value;
        }
    }

    public BinarySearchTree Left
    {
        get
        {
            return this.left;
        }
    }

    public BinarySearchTree Right
    {
        get
        {
            return this.right;
        }
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        BinarySearchTree current_node = this;
        while (current_node.left != null && current_node.right != null)
        {
            if (value <= current_node.value)
            {
                current_node = current_node.left;
            }
            else
            {
                current_node = current_node.right;
            }
        }
        if (value <= current_node.value)
        {
            current_node.left = new BinarySearchTree(value);
            //return current_node;
        }
        else
        {
            current_node.right = new BinarySearchTree(value);
            //return current_node;
        }
    }

    public BinarySearchTree GetValueAtNode()
    {
        
    }
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        BinarySearchTree current_node = this;
        stacks.Push(current_node);
        while (stacks.Count != 0){
            if (current_node.left != null)
            {
                stacks.Push(current_node);
                current_node = current_node.left;
            }
            yield return stacks.Peek().value;
            current_node = stacks.Peek().right;
            stacks.Pop();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
BinarySearchTreeTests.Can_sort_complex_tree:
    Outcome: Failed
    Error Message:
    System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Stack Trace:
       at BinarySearchTree.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext() in c:\Users\320145763\Exercism\csharp\binary-search-tree\BinarySearchTree.cs:line 78
   at BinarySearchTreeTests.Can_sort_complex_tree() in c:\Users\320145763\Exercism\csharp\binary-search-tree\BinarySearchTreeTests.cs:line 84
```

And the relevant unit test is:

```
using System.Linq;
using Xunit;

public class BinarySearchTreeTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Can_sort_complex_tree()
    {
        var tree = new BinarySearchTree(new[] { 2, 1, 3, 6, 7, 5 });
        Assert.Equal(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 }, tree.AsEnumerable());
    }
}
```

Comment: Private member `stacks` doesn't look like it's been initialized anywhere. You're probably getting a NullReferenceException here : `stacks.Push(current_node)`. Make sure to include the full exception including the message and line information so we can better assist you.

Comment: The error message is updated in the question

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- The `while` condition in `Add` is not correct, it could be that *just one* child reference is `null` and that the code that follows the `while` loop will overwrite the existing child reference, whereby you will potentially lose part of the tree. It is probably easiest to do a `while (true)` and break out of the loop as soon as in the direction of choice there is no child and a new node is created to fill that gap.
- `stacks` should not be an instance member, but a variable local to `GetEnumerator` as otherwise you will get two executing `GetEnumerator` iterators to interfere which each other's stack needs.
- `stacks` is never initialised to be an actual `Stack` instance. You need `new Stack<BinarySearchTree>()` somewhere...
- The logic of `GetEnumerator` is not (entirely) correct. For instance `current_node = stacks.Peek().right;` may assign `null` to `current_node` so that you get an exception in the next iteration.

Here is a correction to the two impacted methods:

```
    public void Add(int value)
    {
        BinarySearchTree current_node = this;
        while (true)
        {
            if (value <= current_node.value) {
                if (current_node.left == null) {
                    current_node.left = new BinarySearchTree(value);
                    break;
                }
                current_node = current_node.left;
            } else {
                if (current_node.right == null) {
                    current_node.right = new BinarySearchTree(value);
                    break;
                }
                current_node = current_node.right;
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Stack<BinarySearchTree> stacks = new Stack<BinarySearchTree>();
        stacks.Push(this);
        while (stacks.Count != 0){
            BinarySearchTree current_node = stacks.Peek();
            while (current_node.left != null) {
                current_node = current_node.left;
                stacks.Push(current_node);
            }
            while (stacks.Count != 0){
                current_node = stacks.Peek();
                yield return current_node.value;
                stacks.Pop();
                if (current_node.right != null) {
                    stacks.Push(current_node.right);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```